# Changing function in an object's member

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to write a very simple game using C++ and SDL2. I have a `gameObject` class and a `player` object. I am trying to change the `update` function for the player member only. This is because in the future, I might add something like an enemy object and have different `update` code for that.

Please help, or if you have an idea of a better way to do this, please let me know.

`player.Update();` needs to be different than `enemy.Update();` both of which are in the `gameObject` class.

Comment: Read up about `virtual` methods and Polymorphism. Declare `Update()` as `virtual` in `gameObject`. Derive separate `Player` and `Enemy` classes from `gameObject` and have them `override`  the `Update()` method to do different things as needed.

Comment: Thanks. I did that and It's working perfectly